# Two segments of code (in javascript's canvas) that are nearly identical to each other have vastly different behavior

Tags: javascript, canvas

`draw()` draws a single 8x8 square as expected (every 100ms, but this bit of code is not included). `afl_draw()` draws a huge random square when run. Can anyone help me find out what is going on?

Relevant code:

Game = {

```
draw: function(cycle) {
    Game.ctx.fillStyle = cycle.color;
    Game.ctx.beginPath();
    Game.ctx.moveTo(cycle.x - (cycle.width / 2), cycle.y - (cycle.height / 2));
    Game.ctx.lineTo(cycle.x + (cycle.width / 2), cycle.y - (cycle.height / 2));
    Game.ctx.lineTo(cycle.x + (cycle.width / 2), cycle.y + (cycle.height / 2));
    Game.ctx.lineTo(cycle.x - (cycle.width / 2), cycle.y + (cycle.height / 2));
    Game.ctx.closePath();
    Game.ctx.fill();

},
//afl: account for lag
afl_draw : function(cycle,positions){
    $(positions).each(function(i, item){


        item_split = item.split(',');
        item_x = item_split[0];
        item_y = item_split[1];

        console.log(item_x, item_y);

        Game.ctx.fillStyle = cycle.color;
        Game.ctx.beginPath();
        Game.ctx.moveTo(item_x - (cycle.width / 2), item_y - (cycle.height / 2));
        Game.ctx.lineTo(item_x + (cycle.width / 2), item_y - (cycle.height / 2));
        Game.ctx.lineTo(item_x + (cycle.width / 2), item_y + (cycle.height / 2));
        Game.ctx.lineTo(item_x - (cycle.width / 2), item_y + (cycle.height / 2));
        Game.ctx.closePath();
        Game.ctx.fill();    
    });
},
```

}

The full code is at apollius.com/static/js/app.js

Comment: What do you expect your code to do, and what it does instead? By declaring your variables you can get rid of many issues.

Comment: I expect `afl_draw()` to perform the same behavior as `draw()`, drawing an 8x8 square for each position inputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you convert *item_x* and *item_y* to Integers before using them.
Remember, *String.split()* outputs an array of Strings.

So instead of this:

```
item_split = item.split(',');
item_x = item_split[0];
item_y = item_split[1];
```

Do this:

```
item_split = item.split(',');
item_x = parseInt(item_split[0], 10);
item_y = parseInt(item_split[1], 10);
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/2sunrthq/

**Red** rectangle: drawn with the first working draw function.
**Blue** rectangle: drawn with the second non-working draw function.
**Green** rectangle: drawn with the now working second draw function.